# Symbol appearance is ok on my computer, but different on other

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have HTML page, and there are symbols as alpha, omega etc. Why i have it OK on my computer, but wrong on other? Is it problem with encoding or font issues?

On my pc: α

Other   : ╬▒

Comment: It's could be font, encodings, or something else maybe?  You may need to set the right response type.
https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index

Comment: Question is not related to programming, what you are having is a computer configuration issue.

Comment: @hidden_4003 Or, they could simply have misspelled the meta charset command. We don't know.

Comment: Mike, it is already utf-8

Answer (score 0):

add the correct encoding on your web.config.

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

Its also depend how you save your asp.net file. If you save it as code page 1253 (that is the Greek for alpha -> α) or UTF-8. Its better to save it as utf-8 and show it as utf-8

about globalization https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.100)

### for html files

you declare the charset right after the header as:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

for utf-8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Comment: I'm not using my Asp project as main, my page is separated, and asp net only for requests.

Comment: @narayanaraghavendra  When you use a simple html file, then you can use the above meta as I type it - you just need to use the correct charset that is the same as the one you save your html files.

Comment: it didn't help :(

Comment: If it was not utf-8, i would have problems also with "<>" symbols wouldn't i? But everything is ok except these Greek symbols.